# Setting background image on dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set a background image on a dynamically created element however it does not seem to be working. It is supposed to take the "img" property of an object that I have put into an array and then use that for the background image url.

Javascript:

```
var sponsorArray = new Array();

//Sponsor Constructor Function
function Sponsor(name, img, tier, url, description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.img = img;
    this.tier = tier;
    this.url = url;
    this.description = description;

    //A counter for the number of sponsors
    Sponsor.num = (Sponsor.num || 0) + 1;

    //Insert this object into the sponsors array
    sponsorArray.push(this);
};

var sponsor0 = new Sponsor(
    'test sponsor',
    './images/sponsors/test.png',
    'Platinum',
    'test.com',
    'blah blah blah'
);

var initSponsors = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sponsorArray.length; i++) {

        var sponsor_image = $('<li>', {
            'class': 'sponsor-logo',
            'id': 'sponsor' + i,
            'background-image': 'url(\'' + sponsorArray[i].img + '\')'
        });

        $('#logo-sponsors').append(sponsor_image);
    }
};

initSponsors();
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="logo-sponsors">
</ul>
```

When I inspect the element it appears that it should work? I'm at a loss...

https://jsfiddle.net/qmr32463/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"background-image"` is an invalid jQuery method. `.css()` on the other hand is valid, so

instead of

```
        'background-image' : 'url(\'' + sponsorArray[i].img + '\')'
```

Use:

```
        css : {
          backgroundImage: 'url(\'' + sponsorArray[i].img + '\')'
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qmr32463/1/

Comment: Well that was frustrating... Thanks!